# codigo javascript a JSX en GATSBY?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby

```
import React from 'react'
import './index.css'


export default function index() {
  return (
    <div className="contenedor" onload="onLoad()" id="myDiv" 
 style= {{display:'none'}}>
  <img className="portada"src="image url" alt=""/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

HOLA, este es el codigo que tengo en el index de mi proyecto en gatsby

y esto es lo que quiero convertir a JSX, ayuda porfa!

```
  function onLoad() {
        var showDiv;
        if(localStorage.getItem ("showDiv") == null) {
            showDiv = true;
        }
        else {
            showDiv = localStorage.getItem ("showDiv")
        }

        if (showDiv) {
      document.getElementById ('myDiv') .style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById ('myDiv') .remove();
        }
    }

    function onClose() {
        document.getElementById ('myDiv') .remove();
        localStorage.setItem("showDiv", false);
    }
```

y esto es lo que he traducido hasta ahora en JSX...

```
import React from 'react'


const onLoad = () => { 
var showDiv;
if (localStorage.getItem ("showDiv") == null) {
    let showDiv = true;
}
    else {
        showDiv = localStorage.getItem ("showDiv")
    }
    if (showDiv) {
        document.getElementById ('myDiv').style.display = 'block';
   }
   else {
       document.getElementById ('myDiv').remove();
   }

};

const onClose = () =>{
    document.getElementById ('myDiv').remove();
        localStorage.setItem("showDiv", false);
}
```

en la terminal me muestran estos warnings/errores

1:8   warning  'React' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

4:7   warning  'onLoad' is assigned a value but never used   no-unused-vars

21:11  warning  'onClose' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 3 problems (0 errors, 3 warnings)

ayuda porfa!

---

entonces este es mi componente

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css'



 function COM() {
      /* cualquier codigo javascript va aqui??? */
     return (
 <div className="contenedor">
 <img className="portada" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/lenguaestudiocreativo/image/upload/v1626228418/hportada_jgljqd.svg" alt=""/>
  </div>
     )
 }

 export default COM
```

---

y este  es mi index principal

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import './COM';


export default function index() {
  return (
    <Com />
  )
};
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor no utilices imágenes para mostrar tu código, puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el código en texto, también puedes revisar [ask].

Comment: También puedes especificar un poco mas que problema presentas, el único problema que puedo ver es que no regresar un componente como se espera en el `return`

Comment: hola Richard, pues ya estuve tratando de llegar a un codigo parecido, pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @Richard, no entiendo eso que dices de **return**, quiero llegar a algo parecido del codigo de javascript en JSX, pero eso no tiene **return**

Comment: Todo componente en react tiene un `return` para regresar el html que quieres mostrar, dame unos minutos y realizo un ejemplo básico, para ayudarte a entender un poco mejor como puedes pasar tu código a react, puedes revisar un poco la [documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Comment: **@Richard**, si yo he visto eso, pero me gustaria saber si existe alguna manera de hacerlo lo mas parecido posible al codigo de javascript, para asi tener separado la funcion jsx de html de la funcion esta que quiero tener en otro file, y es que tambien fijo no entiendo esa funcion de jsx donde tiene un return con el html

Comment: ahora solo reduje los warnings a 3, de esos tres dice que ni react esta siendo usado ni las funciones onload y onclose!...?

Comment: y pues no entiendo esto, porque parece mas bien como si estuviera cerca de la solucion, pues no me vota ningun error de por si, es como si faltara algo

Comment: bueno puedes tener separado tu js de tus componentes, pero en react, ya no se utiliza `document.getElementById` por que tu interfaz la creas con ayuda de react

Comment: este es el link del ejemplo de donde me estoy guiando...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61695278/how-to-window-addeventlistener-in-react-js

Comment: deberia usar query selector en vez del id?, el problema es que me dice que react no esta siendo usado...

Comment: quite el **import React from 'react'** y ahora solo quede con 2 warnings

Comment: El `getElementById` es utilizado para obtener la referencia de un elemento `html`, no se como funciona `gatsby` pero `react` crea `apartir` de los componentes creados y utilizados, y por lo que veo la [documentación de gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-2/) funciona casi igual.

Comment: y entonces esta funcion **const onLoad = () => {      }**  necesita un return y no necesita el **import React from 'react'** ?

Comment: **const onLoad = () => {
              return (
                       <div>
                
                       </div>
                 );
             }
    
           export default com;**

Comment: esta es la supuesta funcion en gatsby en donde si acepta el **import React from 'react'**,pero apenas le agrego el **if and else** staement se vuelve a quebrar

Comment: uy es que a lo bien, con solo quitarle el **<div> </div>** ya deja de funcionar el **import React from 'react'**

Comment: uyyy todo bien **@Richard**, tomese su tiempo hehe, uyy pero si porfa si conoce a alquien que me ayude a traducir ese codigo **a**  JSX, se lo agradeceria, pues es que tengo varios codigos parecidos asi en javascript donde hago scrolltop, elementos que aparezcan del left right en scroll, funciones de botones etc, todo en javascript, y si al parecer lo unico que necesitaria seria saber como traducir esa funcion de javascript en JSX.....y que funcione en GATSBY <3

Comment: aunque si ud tiene una solucion apropiada para JSX, pues si tambien, es que estuve checkeando eso del **return** que me dijo y si creo que de eso se trata **JSX** de crear componentes y hacerles el css a esos componentes y pasarlos al index principal y eso, como capas sobre capas, **con el html y el javascript incluido**, entonces si todo bien cualquier cosa me comenta

Comment: Para agregar información nueva a tu pregunta o mejorar la misma, por favor usa la opción de [edit] y agrega le código nuevo y errores que presentes.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno por lo que entiendo `onLoad` es el componente que quieres renderizar, y suponiendo que lo llamaras en tu index, el cual debe funcionar sin problemas.

También suponiendo que entiendo bien tu código, basado en lo que tienes en `localStorage.getItem ("showDiv")` mostraras un `div` basado en esa condición.

Se me ocurre que tu código puede quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
import React from 'react';

const OnLoad = () => {
    let textoDiv = 'texto defeault';
    let showDiv = false;
    let testComponent = (<div>component default</div>);

    if (localStorage.getItem("showDiv") == null) {
        showDiv = true;
        textoDiv = 'miDiv';
    }
    else {
        showDiv = localStorage.getItem("showDiv");
        textoDiv ='miDiv con else';
    }
    if (showDiv) {
        testComponent = <div>componente cumpliendo showDiv</div>
    }
    else {
        testComponent = <div>componente NO cumpliendo showDiv</div>
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {textoDiv}
                {testComponent}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default OnLoad;
```

Cambie `onLoad` por `OnLoad` ya que es costumbre definir los componentes con la primera mayúscula y distinguirlos así de código `html`.

Elimine los `document` debido a que aquí no se hace referencia a código `html` de manera tradicional

En cuanto a usar tu scroll puedes revisar un poco la documentación de Gatsby sobre [Scroll Restoration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/scroll-restoration/#gatsby-skip-here) no se si sea lo que quieres pero puede ayudarte un poco.

---

### Ejemplo básico para usar un componente o componentes

Al crear un proyecto [CRA(Create React App)](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app), solemos tener un `index.js` o `index.jsx` con la siguiente estructura

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Ahora creamos 2 componentes básicos para utilizarlos en el index.

**Componente 1**

```
import React from 'react';

const MiComponente1 = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Componente 1</h1>
        </>
    );
}
export default MiComponente1;
```

**Componente 2**

```
import React from 'react';

const MiComponente2 = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h5>Mi Componente 2</h5>
        </>
    );
}
export default MiComponente2;
```

Para visualizar estos 2 componentes los importamos en el **index** de la siguiente manera.

```
import MiComponente1 from 'pages/testPromise';
import MiComponente2 from 'pages/testComponente';
```

Al usarlos, queda nuestro index de la siguiente manera.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import MiComponente1 from 'pages/testPromise';
import MiComponente2 from 'pages/testComponente';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MiComponente1 />
    <MiComponente2 />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Todo esto aplicado a la creación de un proyecto básico de `React`, Tu proyecto esta hecho con gatsby por lo tanto re comiendo que revises la [documentación](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-2/) al respecto para uso con react**

Comment: **@Richard**,  uy bien gracias, espera lo analizo y te comento despues, mañana hehe, dale gracias....este pendiente eh!.

Comment: mejor la otra semana...que voy a ver unos tutoriales y eso

Comment: hola richard, oye necesito ayuda la verdad no entiendo JSX, me gustaria que me ayudara, entonces primero, para entender JSX y el codigo que me paso arriba pense en simplemente hacer un componente y pasar este al index principal, como paso a paso no?....entonces hise el componente le agregue el javascript con el return y eso, respetando la estructura del JSX, pero no me funciono me boto errores, entonces intente hacer un simple componente ysin nada de javascript y pasarlo al index principal

Comment: entonces mire a continuacion

Comment: @lenguaestudiocreativo Edite mi respuesta para dar un ejemplo mas claro del como funciona un poco los componentes con react, espero te sirva y recomiendo que revises la documentación de **Gatsby**

Comment: si ya lo pude resolver con useffect, gracias por la info bien

Comment: @lenguaestudiocreativo que bien que lo hallas podido resolver, aun que el `useEffect` no tiene mucha relación con el problema que planteas en tu pregunta. Si mi respuesta te sirvio te agradecería que la marques como correcta, caso contrarío agrega tu respuesta(marcala como correcta) y edita tu pregunta para que tenga mas coherencia con el uso de `useEffect`.

Comment: ah pues agrgue el useeffect para entonces poder meter el codigo de javascript y le di return todo esto como componente, si en donde la marco?

Comment: @lenguaestudiocreativo para marcar como respuesta correcta haz clic en la marca(paloma) al lado de la respuesta (debajo del contador de puntos a favor o en contra); al hacer clic, cambiará de gris a verde.
Igual te recomiendo que revises un poco el funcionamiento de react y `useEffect` por que todo el código escrito en los componentes es javaScript por lo tanto no se necesita `useEffect` o depende de el funcionamiento que quieras darle a tu componente.